# Remove record associated with user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a simple friendship feature in my rails/angular app but I'm having some trouble getting the destroy function to work. I thought of a solution, but unsure if it will work, and how to create it.

When a friendship is created a new record (the friendship) is stored in the friendship table,

```
  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Here's the json output of the friendships. The id is the id of the friendship and friend_id is the id of the user that's been friended.

```
{"id":8,"friend_id":2},
{"id":9,"friend_id":3},
{"id":10,"friend_id":4}
```

In my friendship controller I have this,

```
def index
  friends = current_user.friends.as_json(:only => [:id, :friend_id, :name])
  render :json => friends
end
```

Which renders the following.

```
{"id":2,"name":"Jan Jansen"},
{"id":3,"name":"Kees Keesen"},
{"id":4,"name":"Piet Pietersen"}
```

As you can see the id of the user coincides with the `friend_id` in the friendship.

Now to the problem. This is my remove function,

```
def destroy
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.find params[:id]
  @friendship.destroy
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

The problem here is that the id that is passed is the id of the user and not the id friendship. So if I remove a friendship now I get an error.

> http://localhost:3000/friendships/4.json 404 (Not Found)

There is a link between the user id, friend_id and friendship id. Is it possible to get the friendship id through the user id and or friend_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the friendship id through the user id and or friend_id?

I think your pattern is wrong.

You're trying to find the `id` of the join table; what you *should* be looking for is the `friend_id`:

```
def destroy
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by friend_id: params[:id]
  @friendship.destroy
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

This way - if you pass the `friend_id` to the destroy method, it will find that *friend* for the `current_user`:

```
#app/views/friendships/index.html.erb
<%= current_user.friends.each do |friend| %>
   <%= link_to "Unfriend", user_friendships_path(friend), method: :destroy %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

If you can look up a `friendship` by its `id`, you're likely using a `has_many :through` association:

[image]

As can be seen from the `schema` above, HMT `join tables` have a *`primary key`*, which you're trying to look up with `find`. The problem is this primary key has absolutely *no* relation to the other tables it's referencing.

Since you're trying to identify a `friendship` record in relation to the `current_user`, I presumed you were trying to identify a specific `friend`. The only way to do this would be to look up against the `friend_id` column.

If you had `has_and_belongs_to_many` (a simpler implementation of the tables above), you'd be able to use:

```
 current_user.friendships.find params[:id]
```

... as this links directly to the other table (not the join).

Comment: Hm! It seems to work, but I'm not sure on how it works. Maybe this is a silly question but what is @friendship exactly? I thought it was the record in the friendship table. That's why I wanted to destroy it.

Comment: Thank you so much Rich for taking the time to explain the matter to me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to remove just a friendship so find it by `friend_id` for a user.

```
current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: params[:friend_id]).first
```

So

> http://localhost:3000/friendships/4.json

will match to route: `friendships/:friend_id` for current user